# Why is mapStateToProps needed if I can use the entire store in my component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

From definition

> `mapStateToProps` is used for selecting the part of the data from the store that the connected component needs.

I didn't understand why do we even have to specify `mapStateToProps` if I can use the entire store data in my component, what exactly does `mapStateToProps` provides? What will happen if I select some part of data?

Any advantages?

Comment: *if I can use the entire store data in my component* - can you clarify what you mean by this? For one, its a general best practice to only provide components with the data they need. Especially if you have a complex store, it greatly simplifies the component code by moving some of that filtering/selecting into the `mapStateToProps` function.

Comment: ok lets say If I use the entire store and don't use `mapStateToProps ` then my component will re-render even if any variable in my store changes?

And when I use `mapStateToProps ` then my component will reload only when some of the variable to which I have configured changes? Is it?

Comment: *If I use the entire store* - you still haven't clarified that point. What are you using besides `mapStateToProps`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `mapStateToProps` gives you only the p**arts of the store you need** in the component.
- It **calls every time the store state changes** (every time the relative part of the store that you return is changed).
- It can return different structures of the store data
- Can return different structures of the store data for different component props.
- Can be re-used for different components that need the same parts of the store

Comment: ok lets say If I use the entire store and don't use `mapStateToProps ` then my component will re-render even if any variable in my store changes?

And when I use `mapStateToProps ` then my component will reload only when some of the variable to which I have configured changes? Is it?

Comment: The second statement is correct. I'm not sure about the first. You can read more about `mapStateToProps` on:  https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate